# Hangfire DisableConcurrentExecution attribute was never called

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

Hangfire DisableConcurrentExecution attribute was never called

As per documentation, I have a method that can be called with a different Id and run concurrently. However, I want to stop the method from running concurrently if it's the same Id that being passed. I tried multiple things but the disableconcurrentexecution attribute was just never called. I assume it would work but for some reasons the attribute just didn't get called.

```
public void ScheduleUpsertMethod(int Id)
{
    var result = _scheduler.Schedule<Account>(service => 
    service.doSomething(Id));
}

[AutomaticRetry(OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Fail, Attempts = 3, LogEvents = true)]
[DisableConcurrentExecution 5*60]

public async Task doSomething(int Id)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question here since nobody has replied. I made a mistake of putting the DisableConcurrentExecution with the method. Account is actually an interface and I had to put the DisableConurrentExecution inside the Account Interface for the attribute to be triggered.

Comment: @Thoms Ng -  I am facing same problem. My interface method having "Id" parameter. And I want to stop concurrent execution of method with same Id. It's not working for me with same Id at all. Can you please share you interface if possible.